# What is the formula for this exponentially growing "stairs"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I'm looking for a formula that, given a linear $x$ input, would yield values of $y$ in a "stairs" shape so to speak, in such a way that as the value of $x$ grows higher, the difference between each step is bigger, and it also takes longer to reach the next the step, as this graph (hopefully) illustrates:

[image]

As you have probably guessed by now I'm not a mathematician, but I'm fairly sure this has an easy solution. I've been playing around with modulus and powers but I couldn't quite get the graph above so far.

Edit: Graph updated.

Comment: Do you need all the points (i.e. the where the vertical meets the horizontal) of each step to lie on a straight line?

Comment: @Chuck correct. For instance, a subset sample of $y$ values could look like: [2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 8, 8, 8] etc

Comment: Graph updated, silly me.

Comment: For a linear stepcase, we would assume that without a "floor" function, it could be simplified to the form of $y=kx$. Then using $f(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x)$ simultaneously could achieve this effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My first intuition is $y=2^{\lfloor\log_2\,x\rfloor}$. It's very pretty though:

[image: plot of 2^{\lfloor\log_2\,x\rfloor}]

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the beautified formula.

Comment: Thank you very much, this gets very near what I was after, and with a couple of variables added to the mix it works wonderfully.

Answer (score 2):

Writing $[x]$ for the integer part of $x$, how about $y=[\sqrt x]^2$?

#### Plot

[image: The plot]

Comment: I think that in this case, the width of staircases is growing at a fairly slow pace (slower than exponential). But it fits the given picture better.

Comment: Thanks for adding the plot!

Comment: Great answer, I can't accept two answers but this one also came close, you have my upvote.

Answer (score 1):

It might be too steep for what you want though.

$\large y = \left \lfloor \frac{-1 + \sqrt{8x+1}}{2} \right \rfloor$

#### Plot

[image: A Plot of the function]

Comment: A bit too step indeed but great approach nonetheless, I will remember this formula in case I need it in the future, thanks!